# How to modify variables in an atomic way using REST API

Tags: variables, activiti, camunda

Consider a process instance variable which currently has some value. I would like to update its value, for instance increment it by one, using the REST API of Activiti / Camunda. How would you do this?

The problem is that the REST API has services for setting variable values and to get them. But incorporating such API could easily lead to race condition.

Also consider that my example is regarding integers while a variable could be a complex JSON object or array!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer is for Camunda 7.3.0:

There is no out-of-the-box solution. You can do the following:

1. Extend the REST API with a custom resource that implements an endpoint for variable modification. Since the Camunda REST API uses JAX-RS, it is possible to add the Camunda REST resources to a custom JAX-RS application. See [1] for details.
2. In the custom resource endpoint, implement the read-modify-write cycle in one transaction using a custom command:

   ```
   protected void readModifyWriteVariable(CommandExecutor commandExecutor, final String processInstanceId,
         final String variableName, final int valueToAdd) {

     try {
       commandExecutor.execute(new Command<Void>() {
         public Void execute(CommandContext commandContext) {
           Integer myCounter = (Integer) runtimeService().getVariable(processInstanceId, variableName);

           // do something with variable
           myCounter += valueToAdd;

           // the update provokes an OptimisticLockingException when the command ends, if the variable was updated meanwhile
           runtimeService().setVariable(processInstanceId, variableName, myCounter);

           return null;
         }
       });
     } catch (OptimisticLockingException e) {
       // try again
       readModifyWriteVariable(commandExecutor, processInstanceId, variableName, valueToAdd);
     }
   }
   ```

See [2] for a detailed discussion.

[1] http://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.3/api-references/rest/#overview-embedding-the-api
[2] https://groups.google.com/d/msg/camunda-bpm-users/3STL8s9O2aI/Dcx6KtKNBgAJ

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, but then again it's just suitable for increment! The number of modifications I can think of are endless. Perhaps incorporating some sort of server-side script is more practical. But it's just an idea, I'm still working on it.

Comment: Depending on the payload you submit to the REST resource from the client you can do anything. The payload could even be a script, however then you should be aware of possibilities for remote code execution. Increment is just an example.

Comment: Could you please provide the example in which a script string is uploaded to the server and executed?

Comment: This question is not really Camunda-related. I suggest you read about implementing JAX-RS resources (e.g. http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/json-example-with-jersey-jackson/) and executing scripts in Java (e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/prog_guide/api.html).

Comment: Thorben's answer is certainly not isolated to Camunda. The exact same code he posted will work in Activiti as well (even Activiti 6).

Comment: In this case I´d create a helper process with a single system or script activiti. The start form would have two fields: the target processInstanceId and another field that takes a JSON string where you can list the updates you want. The system or script task would process the update requests and save the results in as a result var in the called process, allowing for a thread-safe way to get the updated values.